Range setFormulasLocal: An internal error occurred while processing the request
I'm trying to do this script and get the following "error":
Range setFormulasLocal: An internal error occurred while processing the request.
Following script:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.get.ActiveWorksheet();
    // Insert at range A:A on selectedSheet, move existing cells right
    selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
    // Set range A1:A2 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A1:A2").setFormulasLocal([["STATUS"],["=IF(AND(D2=\"OPEN\", X2=0), \"AGUARDANDO ATENDIMENTO\", IF(AND(D2=\"OPEN\", X2<W2), \"ATENDIMENTO PARCIAL\", IF(AND(D2=\"CLOSED\", X2=W2), \"FECHADO\", IF(AND(D2=\"CANCELED\", X2<W2), \"CANCELADO\", \"ATENDIDO\"))))"]]);
    // Auto fill range
    selectedSheet.getRange("A2").autoFill("A2:A27085", ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault);
    // Auto fit the columns of range A:A on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").getFormat().autofitColumns();
}


I've tested the code w/o issue. Maybe you could try setFormulas.

I changed the formula and made adjustments to the formula. It worked, follow the script
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Inserir na faixa A:A na selectedSheet, movendo as células existentes para a direita
selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
// Definir a fórmula na célula A1
selectedSheet.getRange("A1").setValue("STATUS");
// Definir a fórmula na célula A2
selectedSheet.getRange("A2").setFormula('=IF(AND(E2="OPEN", Y2=0), "AGUARDANDO ATENDIMENTO", IF(AND(E2="OPEN", Y2<X2), "ATENDIMENTO PARCIAL", IF(AND(E2="CLOSED", Y2=X2), "FECHADO", IF(AND(E2="CANCELED", X2<W2), "CANCELADO", "ATENDIDO"))))');
// Auto fill range
selectedSheet.getRange("A2").autoFill("A2:A27085", ExcelScript.AutoFillType.fillDefault);
// Ajustar automaticamente as colunas da faixa A:A na selectedSheet
selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").getFormat().autofitColumns();
}

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
